# Display a CCSprite seven times

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

I am a beginner in Cocos2d and I wanted to display 7 coins in a horizontal pattern. So this is what I wrote in my main gameplay layer:

In my init, I have this

```
coins  = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"coins.png"];
```

I made a method for the coin patterns I want it to be in (display seven times across)

```
- (void)coinPatterns {
    coins.position = ccp(150,150);

    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        coins.position = ccp (coins.position.x + 20, coins.position.y);
        [self addChild:coins];
    }
}
```

And then I added this in my update method

```
[self coinPatterns];
```

But for some reason, my code keeps crashing. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: The reason why code keeps crashing is because of you are adding same object more than one time in your layer.

Comment: Oh, thats why it was crashing.. no wonder..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want to do here is create a separate sprite node for each coin, instead of reusing the same one over and over (I'm not even sure if that works). You would do that like this

```
- (void)coinPatterns {
    NSInteger originalX = 150;
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        CCSprite *coin = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"coins.png"];
        coin.position = ccp(originalX, 150);
        originalX += 20;
        [self addChild:coin];
    }
}
```

This creates 7 coins, each spaced by 20. Also, in the code you provided, all 7 coins would have been stacked on top of each other, since the `x` value was never actually incremented. If you use this, it's unnecessary to have the variable or property `coins`.

If you want to access these coins later, for example to see if a character hit into them, you could make an `NSMutableArray` property `coinArray` and then to add each coin to the array add the line `[self.coinArray addObject:coin];` to the for-loop under `[self addChild:coin];`. That would put them all in the array.

To detect a collision, do something along the lines of this

```
- (void)characterMoved:(CCSprite *)character 
{
    for (CCSprite *coin in self.coinArray)
    {
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(coin.frame, character.frame)
            // character and coin collided, add points or remove the coin or something
     }
}
```

This would need you to have a method characterMoved: that fires every time the character moves.

Comment: Thank you so much! This could not have been better explained :)

Comment: Do you know how I can access the NSMutableArray and write to it? I want to detect a collision between the character and the coins. Thanks!